# Grant access to one repository for one specific user on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, access-rights

I have many private repositories on BitBucket in my Team account. I have admin rights. It's a free team account.

Can I give access for only one specific private repository with only read rights for someone outside my team? I would like to give an opportunity to clone this private repository for one person. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - go to that repo's admin panel and grant that user read access. Your change will only apply to that one repository.

Comment: It gives access to all repositories in a project